# Why $\bf \bar D$ displays as ``7016D in the pdf generated bookmark using hyperref package

Tags: hyperref

I am using the the hyperref package in an arxiv preprint in RevTeX format.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, urlcolor = blue, linkcolor= blue, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
```

However, one of my sections is defined as

```
\section{${\bf D}$, ${\bf \bar D}$ and ${\bf J/Psi}$ $-$ Potential Candidates}
```

The `\bf` command has been used since the format, by default bolds out the headings. However, symbols aren't given that treatment automatically. Hence, this form displays correctly.

The problem is - the part corresponding to `${\bf \bar D}$` displays in the bookmark as

> ``7016D

instead of the desired form.

Q1. Why does that happen?

Q2. Any work-around?

Thanks :)

Comment: The `\bf` command has been obsolete and deprecated for more than twenty years.

Comment: Check your logs. PDF bookmarks cannot contain all characters, and hyperref usually warns you about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\bf` has been deprecated for more than twenty years. If you really want that the math in the title is enboldened, use `\boldmath`. But for `hyperref` you also need `\texorpdfstring`, for getting in the bookmark an approximate representation.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{\protect\boldmath
  \texorpdfstring{$D$}{D},
  \texorpdfstring{$\bar D$}{D̄} and
  \texorpdfstring{$J/\Psi$}{J/Ψ} -- Potential Candidates}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `D̄` has been obtained with `D` followed by U+0304 (COMBINING MACRON).

Don't use `$-$` for an en-dash, but `--`.

Comment: I'm novice - three issues:  1. Why inputenc?  2. Why unicode?   3. I didn't follow how you got the ${\bar D}$     Thanks:)

Comment: @New_new_newbie UTF-8 is necessary to typeset D̄ and Ψ in the bookmarks, where no typesetting takes place. You can simply change them to `Dbar` and `Psi` if you're not able to type them in or don't want to use extended Unicode. The bookmark will have `Dbar` and `Psi`, but it will readable.

Comment: But what exactly is that number 7016 ? Some code for producing overline, which hasn't worked out well, and hence, shows up?

Comment: @New_new_newbie `"7016` is the internal representation of the bar in TeX; when `hyperref` tries to build the bookmark, it does the best it can, but the deprecated command `\bf` ruins every attempt.